# ¿Cómo ajustar el tamaño de un gráfico de velas japonesas hecho con MatPlotLibFinance para que se muestren todas las medias móviles en Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, gráficas, ciencia-de-datos, visualización-de-datos

### Introducción

Recientemente aprendí a graficar `Medias Móviles Simples` (*abreviadas "SMA" por sus siglas en inglés*) usando la librería de [`MatPlotLibFinance`](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance) en `Python3`, las `Medias Móviles Simples` son líneas de tendencia que ayudan al inversionista en la determinación de buenos momentos para entrar a comprar o vender un activo.

### Datos

Las siguientes variables contienen los datos empleados en el Script para graficar la acción del precio, la primera variable se nombró como `df_trading_pair` y contiene la siguiente información:

| Index | Start Date | Open Price | High Price | Low Price | Close Price | Volume | End Date | Abs((CP-OP)/CP)*100 | Low SMA 9 | Close SMA 25 | High SMA 99 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-10-23 23:42:00 | 29.24 | 29.28 | 29.24 | 29.25 | 2145.0 | 2022-10-23 23:44:59.999 | 0.03 | 29.195555555555554 | 29.236400000000003 | 28.95191919191919 |
| 1 | 2022-10-23 23:45:00 | 29.25 | 29.27 | 29.24 | 29.24 | 2233.0 | 2022-10-23 23:47:59.999 | 0.03 | 29.192222222222224 | 29.239199999999997 | 28.95848484848485 |
| 2 | 2022-10-23 23:48:00 | 29.24 | 29.24 | 29.23 | 29.23 | 1399.0 | 2022-10-23 23:50:59.999 | 0.03 | 29.193333333333335 | 29.2316 | 28.96454545454545 |
| 3 | 2022-10-23 23:51:00 | 29.23 | 29.24 | 29.21 | 29.21 | 2603.0 | 2022-10-23 23:53:59.999 | 0.07 | 29.19888888888889 | 29.2284 | 28.97060606060606 |
| 4 | 2022-10-23 23:54:00 | 29.22 | 29.3 | 29.22 | 29.25 | 5576.0 | 2022-10-23 23:56:59.999 | 0.1 | 29.209999999999997 | 29.228 | 28.977575757575757 |
| 5 | 2022-10-23 23:57:00 | 29.24 | 29.28 | 29.23 | 29.26 | 3848.0 | 2022-10-23 23:59:59.999 | 0.07 | 29.221111111111114 | 29.226799999999997 | 28.983636363636364 |
| 6 | 2022-10-24 00:00:00 | 29.26 | 29.34 | 29.25 | 29.27 | 9973.0 | 2022-10-24 00:02:59.999 | 0.03 | 29.22666666666667 | 29.2288 | 28.990202020202016 |
| 7 | 2022-10-24 00:03:00 | 29.28 | 29.36 | 29.26 | 29.34 | 11754.0 | 2022-10-24 00:05:59.999 | 0.2 | 29.234444444444446 | 29.233600000000003 | 28.996969696969696 |
| 8 | 2022-10-24 00:06:00 | 29.34 | 29.44 | 29.33 | 29.41 | 28414.0 | 2022-10-24 00:08:59.999 | 0.24 | 29.245555555555555 | 29.24 | 29.003939393939394 |
| 9 | 2022-10-24 00:09:00 | 29.42 | 29.48 | 29.4 | 29.43 | 21753.0 | 2022-10-24 00:11:59.999 | 0.03 | 29.263333333333335 | 29.248800000000003 | 29.011414141414143 |
| 10 | 2022-10-24 00:12:00 | 29.43 | 29.43 | 29.28 | 29.28 | 9341.0 | 2022-10-24 00:14:59.999 | 0.51 | 29.26777777777778 | 29.2528 | 29.018787878787876 |
| 11 | 2022-10-24 00:15:00 | 29.29 | 29.3 | 29.25 | 29.26 | 3000.0 | 2022-10-24 00:17:59.999 | 0.1 | 29.27 | 29.2556 | 29.024040404040406 |
| 12 | 2022-10-24 00:18:00 | 29.26 | 29.29 | 29.25 | 29.28 | 3065.0 | 2022-10-24 00:20:59.999 | 0.07 | 29.27444444444445 | 29.2588 | 29.029393939393938 |
| 13 | 2022-10-24 00:21:00 | 29.27 | 29.29 | 29.26 | 29.27 | 754.0 | 2022-10-24 00:23:59.999 | 0.0 | 29.278888888888886 | 29.2612 | 29.034444444444443 |
| 14 | 2022-10-24 00:24:00 | 29.28 | 29.33 | 29.28 | 29.33 | 2657.0 | 2022-10-24 00:26:59.999 | 0.17 | 29.284444444444446 | 29.266 | 29.039292929292927 |
| 15 | 2022-10-24 00:27:00 | 29.33 | 29.39 | 29.32 | 29.33 | 3722.0 | 2022-10-24 00:29:59.999 | 0.0 | 29.29222222222222 | 29.2676 | 29.04484848484848 |
| 16 | 2022-10-24 00:30:00 | 29.34 | 29.41 | 29.34 | 29.4 | 3906.0 | 2022-10-24 00:32:59.999 | 0.2 | 29.30111111111111 | 29.2716 | 29.051010101010103 |
| 17 | 2022-10-24 00:33:00 | 29.39 | 29.39 | 29.34 | 29.34 | 3269.0 | 2022-10-24 00:35:59.999 | 0.17 | 29.302222222222227 | 29.274 | 29.056767676767677 |
| 18 | 2022-10-24 00:36:00 | 29.34 | 29.38 | 29.26 | 29.28 | 5719.0 | 2022-10-24 00:38:59.999 | 0.2 | 29.286666666666665 | 29.276 | 29.061818181818182 |
| 19 | 2022-10-24 00:39:00 | 29.28 | 29.29 | 29.23 | 29.25 | 2118.0 | 2022-10-24 00:41:59.999 | 0.1 | 29.281111111111116 | 29.2788 | 29.066060606060606 |
| 20 | 2022-10-24 00:42:00 | 29.24 | 29.24 | 29.21 | 29.23 | 1875.0 | 2022-10-24 00:44:59.999 | 0.03 | 29.276666666666667 | 29.2832 | 29.069999999999997 |
| 21 | 2022-10-24 00:45:00 | 29.23 | 29.25 | 29.21 | 29.24 | 6155.0 | 2022-10-24 00:47:59.999 | 0.03 | 29.272222222222222 | 29.284000000000002 | 29.074242424242424 |
| 22 | 2022-10-24 00:48:00 | 29.23 | 29.23 | 29.18 | 29.19 | 1913.0 | 2022-10-24 00:50:59.999 | 0.14 | 29.263333333333335 | 29.281999999999996 | 29.077777777777776 |
| 23 | 2022-10-24 00:51:00 | 29.19 | 29.2 | 29.13 | 29.14 | 6363.0 | 2022-10-24 00:53:59.999 | 0.17 | 29.246666666666663 | 29.278 | 29.081111111111113 |
| 24 | 2022-10-24 00:54:00 | 29.14 | 29.17 | 29.12 | 29.17 | 8608.0 | 2022-10-24 00:56:59.999 | 0.1 | 29.224444444444444 | 29.275199999999998 | 29.084444444444447 |
| 25 | 2022-10-24 00:57:00 | 29.17 | 29.21 | 29.17 | 29.19 | 2111.0 | 2022-10-24 00:59:59.999 | 0.07 | 29.20555555555556 | 29.272799999999997 | 29.087979797979795 |
| 26 | 2022-10-24 01:00:00 | 29.2 | 29.2 | 29.16 | 29.19 | 2259.0 | 2022-10-24 01:02:59.999 | 0.03 | 29.185555555555556 | 29.270800000000005 | 29.091313131313132 |
| 27 | 2022-10-24 01:03:00 | 29.18 | 29.21 | 29.18 | 29.21 | 1634.0 | 2022-10-24 01:05:59.999 | 0.1 | 29.176666666666662 | 29.27 | 29.094242424242424 |
| 28 | 2022-10-24 01:06:00 | 29.21 | 29.23 | 29.2 | 29.22 | 3276.0 | 2022-10-24 01:08:59.999 | 0.03 | 29.173333333333332 | 29.2704 | 29.0979797979798 |
| 29 | 2022-10-24 01:09:00 | 29.21 | 29.21 | 29.19 | 29.2 | 837.0 | 2022-10-24 01:11:59.999 | 0.03 | 29.171111111111113 | 29.2684 | 29.101717171717173 |

Por su parte, la otra variable denominada `df_trading_pair_date_time_index` contiene la misma información de la anterior variable con ligeras modificaciones, puesto que sólo así puede ser usada en el script de más abajo:

```
def set_DateTimeIndex(df_trading_pair):
    df_trading_pair = df_trading_pair.set_index('Start Date', inplace=False)
    # Rename the column names for best practices
    df_trading_pair.rename(columns = { "Open Price" : 'Open',
                                       "High Price" : 'High',
                                       "Low Price" : 'Low',
                                       "Close Price" :'Close',
                              }, inplace = True)
            
    return df_trading_pair
 # Create another df just to properly plot the data
 df_trading_pair_date_time_index = set_DateTimeIndex(df_trading_pair)
```

### Script

El siguiente script en esencia buscará crear un gráfico de velas japonesas haciendo uso de la información almacenada en las variables `df_trading_pair` y `df_trading_pair_date_time_index`, sus principales detalles están explicados como comentarios dentro del script:

```
import pandas as pd
import mplfinance as mpf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

trading_pair = "SOLBUSD"
# Plotting
# Create my own `marketcolors` style:
mc = mpf.make_marketcolors(up='#2fc71e',down='#ed2f1a',inherit=True)
# Create my own `MatPlotFinance` style:
s  = mpf.make_mpf_style(base_mpl_style=['bmh', 'dark_background'],marketcolors=mc, y_on_right=True)    

# Plot it
# First create a dictionary to store the plots to add
subplots = {'Low SMA 9': mpf.make_addplot(df_trading_pair['Low SMA 9'], width=1, color='#F0FF42'),
            'Close SMA 25': mpf.make_addplot(df_trading_pair['Close SMA 25'], width=1.5, color='#EA047E'),
            'High SMA 99': mpf.make_addplot(df_trading_pair['High SMA 99'], width=2, color='#00FFD1')}

trading_plot, axlist = mpf.plot(df_trading_pair_date_time_index,
                    figratio=(10, 6),
                    type="candle",
                    style=s,
                    tight_layout=True,
                    datetime_format = '%H:%M',
                    ylabel = "Precio ($)",
                    returnfig=True,
                    show_nontrading=True,
                    addplot=list(subplots.values())
                    )

# Add Title
symbol = trading_pair.replace("BUSD","")+"/"+"BUSD"
axlist[0].set_title(f"{symbol} - 3m", fontsize=25, style='italic', fontfamily='fantasy')

# Find which times should be shown every 6 minutes starting at the last row of the df
x_axis_minutes = []
for i in range (1,len(df_trading_pair_date_time_index),2):
    x_axis_minutes.append(df_trading_pair_date_time_index.index[-i].minute)

# Set the main "ticks" to show at the x axis
axlist[0].xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(byminute=x_axis_minutes))

# Set the x axis label
axlist[0].set_xlabel('Zona Horaria UTC')

# Set the SMA legends
# First set the amount of legends to add to the legend box
axlist[0].legend([None]*(len(subplots)+2)) 
# Then Store the legend objects in a variable called "handles", based on this script, your objects to legend will appear from the third element in this list
handles = axlist[0].get_legend().legendHandles
# Finally set the corresponding names for the plotted SMA trends and place the legend box to the upper left corner of the bigger plot
axlist[0].legend(handles=handles[2:],labels=list(subplots.keys()), loc = 'upper left')
```

Finalmente, este script producirá la siguiente imagen:

[image: output1]

### Problema

Al comparar el gráfico impreso por mi script con el gráfico mostrado por Binance:

[image: gráfico de binance]

Se evidencia que la media móvil más grande (la de `99`) no fue impresa como tal, o sí lo fue, ***creo que*** por el tamaño establecido (`figratio=(10, 6)`) para el mismo gráfico esta no aparece.

### La duda

¿Cómo podría hacer una especie de **alejamiento** (*"Zoom Out"*) con el script para que al imprimir el gráfico se alcanze a mostrar la media móvil de 99 sin comprometer mucho la apreciación de los demás elementos impresos en el gráfico?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terminé encontrando una solución, haciendo uso del método [`set_ylim()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-set-ylim) de la librería **MatPlotLib**, el secreto yace en las siguientes líneas:

```
# Set the y axis range 
ymin_value = df_trading_pair[['Low Price','Low SMA 9','Close SMA 25', 'High SMA 99']].min(axis=1).min()
ymax_value = df_trading_pair[['High Price','Low SMA 9','Close SMA 25', 'High SMA 99']].max(axis=1).max()
axlist[0].set_ylim([ymin_value,ymax_value]) #this solves the issue
```

Al establecer un rango fijo de valores que incluyan el valor mínimo de las columnas `['Low Price','Low SMA 9','Close SMA 25', 'High SMA 99']` y el valor máximo de las columnas `['High Price','Low SMA 9','Close SMA 25', 'High SMA 99']` se asegura que este programa producirá la correcta gráfica de la información almacenada en las variables `df_trading_pair` y `df_trading_pair_date_time_index` para cualquier contexto dado (*Supongo*)

## Script

```
# Plotting
# Create my own `marketcolors` style:
mc = mpf.make_marketcolors(up='#2fc71e',down='#ed2f1a',inherit=True)
# Create my own `MatPlotFinance` style:
s  = mpf.make_mpf_style(base_mpl_style=['bmh', 'dark_background'],marketcolors=mc, y_on_right=True)    

# Plot it
# First create a dictionary to store the plots to add
subplots = {'Low SMA 9': mpf.make_addplot(df_trading_pair['Low SMA 9'], width=1, color='#F0FF42'),
            'Close SMA 25': mpf.make_addplot(df_trading_pair['Close SMA 25'], width=1.5, color='#EA047E'),
            'High SMA 99': mpf.make_addplot(df_trading_pair['High SMA 99'], width=2, color='#00FFD1')}

trading_plot, axlist = mpf.plot(df_trading_pair_date_time_index,
                    figratio=(10, 6),
                    type="candle",
                    style=s,
                    tight_layout=True,
                    datetime_format = '%H:%M',
                    ylabel = "Precio ($)",
                    returnfig=True,
                    show_nontrading=True,
                    addplot=list(subplots.values())
                    )

# Add Title
symbol = trading_pair.replace("BUSD","")+"/"+"BUSD"
axlist[0].set_title(f"{symbol} - 3m", fontsize=25, style='italic', fontfamily='fantasy')

# Find which times should be shown every 6 minutes starting at the last row of the df
x_axis_minutes = []
for i in range (1,len(df_trading_pair_date_time_index),2):
    x_axis_minutes.append(df_trading_pair_date_time_index.index[-i].minute)

# Set the main "ticks" to show at the x axis
axlist[0].xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(byminute=x_axis_minutes))

# Set the x axis label
axlist[0].set_xlabel('Zona Horaria UTC')
# Set the y axis range 
ymin_value = df_trading_pair[['Low Price','Low SMA 9','Close SMA 25', 'High SMA 99']].min(axis=1).min()
ymax_value = df_trading_pair[['High Price','Low SMA 9','Close SMA 25', 'High SMA 99']].max(axis=1).max()
axlist[0].set_ylim([ymin_value,ymax_value])

# Set the SMA legends
# First set the amount of legends to add to the legend box
axlist[0].legend([None]*(len(subplots)+2)) 
# Then Store the legend objects in a variable called "handles", based on this script, your objects to legend will appear from the third element in this list
handles = axlist[0].get_legend().legendHandles
# Finally set the corresponding names for the plotted SMA trends and place the legend box to the upper left corner in the bigger plot
axlist[0].legend(handles=handles[2:],labels=list(subplots.keys()), loc = 'upper left', fontsize = 15)
```

`Output:`

[image: output]